# How do I tell winetricks to work with a different prefix?

Tags: wine, winetricks

I'm trying to enable alsa on different prefix than default through winetricks.  More specifically, the prefix that has Rosetta Stone on it, as it cannot see my microphone.

When I open winetricks, it only lets me select default.  I tried anyway, on default, and it did not resolve the issue.

I saw some answers online, through the terminal, but that didn't work either.  Maybe I have the syntax wrong?

```
steve@stevelap:~$ WINEPREFIX=~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Rosetta sh winetricks alsa
sh: 0: Can't open winetricks
steve@stevelap:~$ sudo WINEPREFIX=~/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Rosetta sh winetricks alsa
[sudo] password for steve: 
sh: 0: Can't open winetricks
```

Could anyone please offer assistance?  Thanks!

Comment: Curious!  When I double-checked the Audio tab for that prefix's winecfg, the driver says winealsa.drv.  The problem must lie elsewhere, this is unfortunate.  I will keep looking.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the answer to my question.

The following worked for me:

```
WINEPREFIX=/home/steve/.PlayOnLinux/wineprefix/Rosetta winetricks
```

It launched the GUI, and when I selected default then clicked browse files, it brought me to the Rosetta prefix to confirm.

Comment: (Although still no luck getting microphone to work in Rosetta Stone.  D'oh!)

Comment: YES!!! This was the key to my problems! I've been using the wrong Wine prefix for winetricks/winecfg! Thank you!